# Protect sub folders from direct access but allow system access

Tags: iis, web-config

I'm looking to protect certain subfolder (includes) and files within from direct access from users but I need to retain full permissions & access to the website/system. I'm using IIS on Server 2012 R2. Is this possible ?
Thanks in advance.

example :

```
www.mysite.com/includes/myfile.aspx
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what Hidden Segments is for (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/hiddensegments/index).  The default configuration for IIS protects against folders like "bin".

Answer (score 0):

Folder, for example /Database/ folder, so input `.htaccess` file with `DENY FROM ALL` and php include in index.php